# String field in KSQL TABLE or STREAM containing part of original JSON message

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Is it possible to add string field to KSQL table/stream which will contain part of original message's JSON.

For example,

Original message:

```
{userId:12345, 
 service:"service-1", 
 "debug":{
          "msg":"Debug message", 
          "timer": 11.12}
}
```

So, we need to map `userId` to `userId BIGINT`, `service` to `service STRING` and `debug` to `debug STRING` which will contain `{"msg":"Debug message", "timer": 11.12}` as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply declare it as a `VARCHAR`. From there you can treat it as just a string that happens to be JSON, or you can manipulate it further with the `EXTRACTJSONFIELD` function.

Send sample message to topic:

```
echo '{"userId":12345, "service":"service-1", "debug":{ "msg":"Debug message", "timer": 11.12} }' | kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t test_topic -P
```

Declare the stream:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM demo (userid BIGINT, service VARCHAR, debug VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
```

Query the columns:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.
ksql> SELECT USERID, SERVICE, DEBUG FROM demo;
12345 | service-1 | {"msg":"Debug message","timer":11.12}
```

Access nested JSON fields:

```
ksql> SELECT USERID, SERVICE, EXTRACTJSONFIELD(DEBUG,'$.msg') FROM demo;
12345 | service-1 | Debug message

ksql> SELECT USERID, SERVICE, EXTRACTJSONFIELD(DEBUG,'$.timer') FROM demo;
12345 | service-1 | 11.12
```